# How can i serialize variable with type of Int64 in JavaScript without loss of accuracy?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, serialization, int64

How can i serialize variable with type of Int64 in JavaScript without loss of accuracy?
   My development platform is. NET.

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you're trying to do? JavaScript can reliably handle integers up to 2^53. If you have a number on the server that's 64 bits, you'll have to break it into high and low parts for JavaScript's usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the Int64 coming from? Why do you need it to be Int64 in JavaScript? Do you just need it as a string? Some code would help.

If you need a JavaScript bigint library, there's one [here](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js).